# Jape grammar to identify product release

Tags: text, nlp, grammar, logical-operators, gate

How can i use AND operation on jape grammar?. I just want to check whether a sentence contain 'organisation','jobtitle','person' all together in any order. How it possible? There is '|'(OR) operation allowed but i didnt see any documentation about AND operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't an "and" operator like that as such but you could do it with a set of `contains` checks:

```
Rule: OrgTitlePer
({Sentence contains {Organization},
  Sentence contains {JobTitle},
  Sentence contains {Person}}):sent
-->
:sent.Interesting = {}
```

When you have several constraints within the same set of braces that involve the same annotation type on the left (`Sentence` in this case) then all the constraints must be satisfied simultaneously *by the same annotation*.

Comment: Thanks dude. It works for me. One more help i needed. I have a custom list, which i need to check whether any of words in that list contains in that sentence. What should i do ?

Comment: @Vaisakh use a gazetteer to annotate the list of words with a suitable Lookup and then you can check for `{Sentence contains {Lookup.majorType="whatever"}}`

Comment: Yeaahh.. I got it. Thank you Ian Robert. I went through your suggestion and found how to do the same here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21711634/how-can-i-add-custom-annotations-to-default-annie-gazetteer)

Comment: Can i use a macro in 'Sentence contain' statement ?. I mean like Macro: MULTIPLE
(
 {Token.string=="new"}{Lookup.majorType=="jobtitle"}
) 
Rule: CustomRules({Sentence contains MULTIPLE })

Comment: @Vaisakh no, the right hand side of the contains must be a single constraint.  If you want to check for a complex pattern you need to use a multi phase grammar, annotate occurrences of the complex pattern in one phase with a temporary annotation type and then check in the second phase for `{Sentence contains {TemporaryAnnotation}}`